# What is the best way to support project code for several clients?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, git, project

We have a project (asp.net, js, css, code behind, etc..) and some clients (a couple for example).
What's the best way to develop and support project for several clients? 
The clients has different css, images and some js code inside theirs project, but big part of web forms,css,js and server code is uniform.
Maybe git branches help us, maybe composite controls, or other solutions?

Comment: I would suggest as model similar to how WordPress operates and make your base site run fine how it is then allow it to be overridden. You can then just import the binaries of your base project into the new project which has the client files.

Comment: Are you looking for a source safe ?

Comment: sourse safe is not important now

Answer (score 1):

With Git you have single solution: "Branch Per Client". Period

Comment: @IlyaKlementiev - support additional "Vanilla" branch, changes from which are populated to endusers-branches